# Autenticação não funciona após executar o comando make:auth

Tags: laravel, auth, artisan

Executo o comando:

```
SmartFlex> php artisan migrate
```

dentro do meu projeto e ele é finalizado corretamente. As opções de *login* e registro ficam disponíveis na *view*, mas ao tentar acessar o registro, por exemplo, ocorre o erro abaixo:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:
>   in RouteCollection.php line 179
>   at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
>   at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
>   at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
>   at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
>   at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
>   at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
>   at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
>   at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
>   at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
>   at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
>   at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
>   at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

Já olhei em diversos *post* sobre problemas de rota mais nada funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro pode acontecer caso as rotas de autenticação não estejam registradas corretamente no seu arquivo de rotas.

Para confirmar isso, execute o comando abaixo e veja se as rotas referentes a autenticação estão registradas:

```
php artisan route:list
```

[image: Console]

Na documentação do Laravel podemos encontrar:

> Want to get started fast? Just run php artisan make:auth and php
>   artisan migrate in a fresh Laravel application. Then, navigate your
>   browser to http://your-app.dev/register or any other URL that is
>   assigned to your application. These two commands will take care of
>   scaffolding your entire authentication system!

Antes de executar `php artisan migrate` precisamos executar `php artisan make:auth`.

Por baixo dos panos, temos os seguintes passos que são feitos por esses comandos:

- Criação das rotas de autenticação

  Nesse passo são incluídas as seguintes rotas no `routes/web.php`

  ```
  Auth::routes();

  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
  ```

  Essas rotas apontam para os controllers que são criados junto com a instalação do Laravel em `app\Http\Controllers\Auth`
- Criação das views de autenticação

  Aqui são criados os scaffolds das views para login e registros, em `resources/views/auth`
- Tabelas no banco de dados

  O comando `php artisan migrate` vai executar as migrations de banco de dados que estão em `database/migrations`. O Laravel inclui duas tabelas que são criadas para autenticação, a tabela `user` e a `password_resets`.